# How to change the action bar background color using Appcompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, background-color, android-appcompat

Yes, I know there are a lot of similar questions and answers in the internet. I checked all of them for the last three hours. No solution worked for me.

I simply started an Android Studio (v1.0.2) Project, which is by default provided by the v7 AppCompat Library.

I changed styles.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/MyAppTheme">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

... and inside AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme"
```

I'm looking for the easiest way to change the background color of the Action Bar globally to a desired color.

Right now the action bar is completely white with three black dots for the menu button.

Comment: Well I've discovered a lot of basic app examples to explore in AS. Maybe there's no other documentation for such simple things...

Answer (score 0):

With Appcompat rel 21.0.x just use something like:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Set AppCompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/my_color</item>
    <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@color/my_color_darker</item>

</style>
```

If you want to override the `actionBarStyle` attribute use:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
     <!-- default value is @null -->
     <item name="background">....</item>   
</style>
```